# Dynamically calculate percentage in a datatable

Tags: datatables

How can I dynamically calculate a percentage in a datatable when a search is applied ?
The result should be like this :

```
<tr>
<td>10%</td><td>100</td>
<td>90%</td><td>900</td>
</tr>
```

The percentage should be based on the total of rows shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example shows you a basic approach.

The end result looks like this - note you may get a small rounding error when summing the percentages:

[image]

The code is as follows:

***UPDATE*** - There was a problem with my original solution - it used jQuery to populate DataTable cells with the calculated percentages. That meant DataTables did not respond to sorting/filtering for the percentages column. It's better to use DataTables functions to populate the data cells.

```
<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
   <tr><th>ID</th><th>Amount</th><th>Percent</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>123.4</td><td class="percent"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>234.5</td><td class="percent"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>543.21</td><td class="percent"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>76</td><td class="percent"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>87</td><td class="percent"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({

      // wait for table and data to finish being initialized:
      "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
        populatePercentages();
      }

    });

    function populatePercentages() {
      var total = 0.0;

      // first calcuate the total:
      $('#example').DataTable().rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        // assumes amounts are not null, all numeric, and are in column 2:
        total = total + Number(this.data()[1]); 
      });

      // then calculate the percentage for each row:
      $('#example').DataTable().rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
        var amount = this.data()[1];
        // calculate percent to 2 decimal places:
        var percentage = Math.round((amount / total) * 10000) / 100;
        var cells = $('#example').DataTable().cells(rowIdx, 2);       
        cells.every( function () {
          this.data(percentage);
        });

      });
    }

  });
</script>

</body>
```

Points to note:

1) It uses a "percent" class for the cells where percentages will be shown. This makes selection easier.

2) You can do something similar as (1) for the amounts cells also. I did not, here.

3) The code loops through the table data twice: Once to calculate the grand total amount; and again to calculate the percentages.

4) You would need to adjust assumptions about column offsets to fit your table design.

5) There is more validation which should really be added, to handle missing or non-numeric data, to make the code less brittle.

Handling the case when a search is applied:

**Filtering:**

The above solution can be enhanced to re-calculate percentages when data is filtered.

1) There are two places where the `rows()` function is used. In both places change this to the following: `rows( { search: 'applied' } )`. This will ensure only visible rows are considered when percentages are calculated.

2) Add a new section of code to handle `keyup` events for the search  (filter) box. In my case the selector for this input control is as shown below - but this will need to be edited for other datatables with different IDs (my example table's ID is `example`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      ...
    });

    function populatePercentages() {
      ...
    }

    // catch filter events and re-calculate percentages accordingly:
    $('div#example_filter.dataTables_filter > label > input').keyup(function (e) {
      populatePercentages();
    });

  });
</script>
```

With these changes, a filtered list will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful detailed and step by step answer. I was able to implement this successfully. Just a note for anyone else that might be stumbling on this, you need to implement the keyup event catcher within the populatePercentages function, else it wont be registered, I guess since the table will not have finished loading. 
Thank you again.

Comment: Following up on this, of course you can not put the filter catch inside the populatePercentages function unless you handle recursion...

Comment: @guillottim - I clarified the (unclear!) wording in my answer, to show where the event listener code should be placed.

Comment: Thanks, just for the heads up this didn't work for me (maybe I miswrote it or perhaps the datatables wasn't yet generated when the code was being executed), what I did is I wrapped it inside a function that I executed after init of the datatable.